# Why appears a RuntimeException when I execute this code?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-intent

*When I use this code:*

```
String nombre_del_usuario = getIntent().getStringExtra("nombre");
mensaje.setText("Hola " + nombre_del_usuario + ", bienvenido a mi mundo! ");
```

**Appears this error:**

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>           Process: com.example.ejercicio_de_nombre, PID: 18513
>           java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.ejercicio_de_nombre/com.example.ejercicio_de_nombre.Main2Activity}:
>   java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout cannot be cast to
>   android.widget.TextView
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2678)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2743)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1490)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6165)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:888)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:778)
>            Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout cannot be cast to
>   android.widget.TextView
>               at com.example.ejercicio_de_nombre.Main2Activity.onCreate(Main2Activity.java:21)
>               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6687)
>               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1140)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2631)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2743) 
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
>               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1490) 
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6165) 
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:888) 
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:778)

How can I fix it? Thanks for your help.

Comment: You have never called `setContentView` in your second activity.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know when you call nextActivity(View), but you must add the Main2Activity to the Manifest.

If is not this the error cause, please paste the StackTrace.

Comment: Hello Facu, recently I tried to add it on the Manifest, but, anything happend. But, now I learn more about that error. So, I'll edit this article to can solve this problem. Thanks for your help.